# side by side divs inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 3 divs with the middle div having 2 divs inside side by side. The issue I'm having is that at screen size >768px the 2 divs inside are being squished rather than 100% width? Any help is greatly appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/embedded/result/

The below code is an example of what I'm trying to achieve but there something I'm not catching in the fiddle above thats preventing the below result.

```css
#panel1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #000000;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #0000ff;
}
#panel2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel1">
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>

<div id="panel1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a look: https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/29/embedded/result/

I switched the media to:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
    body { display: block; }
}
```

On the `container` CSS, I added: `min-height: 460px !important;` (The "*important*" notation may be unnecessary, but it worked and I didn't bother testing without it.)

Then in your actual HTML, I fixed a spelling error where you wrote "*containter*" instead of "*container*"

And, finally, I switched `#panel1` to `.panel1` and changed the top and bottom divs to `<div class="panel1"></div>` instead of `<div id="panel1"></div>`. In HTML, you are **NEVER** supposed to give two elements the same ID. Hence why I changed the ID to a class. (*You can reuse classes as much as you want.*)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you have a line:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
    body { display: flex; }
}
```

This is the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thank you! this solved the squishing issue however at screen >768px the bottom 3rd div that should show at the bottom is missing?

Answer (score 0):

To go off of what QuestionMarks said

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
    body { display: flex; }
}
```

Instead of it using flex to display your divs, you need to use this one:

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
        body { display: inline-block; }
    }
```

The key here is using display: inline-block; to display divs side by side.